# How do I target all elements with the same class with getElementByClassName instead of just the first element with that class

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, element, getelementsbyclassname

I'm very new to JS, and really don't understand a lot of it. Trying to learn as I go.

I'm trying to add some new divs to buttons to style them to look like the rest of the buttons on my site as I cant edit the plugins HTML. I've managed to successfully do this for one button. But it won't work for the other buttons. I've tried to read into it and it looks like because I am using getElementsByClassName its only selecting the first button and not the others.

So I dont know if this is right or not and correct me if it ain't. but I think I need to set up a Node loop? so that getElementsByClassName doesn't just select the first node on the page. However I got no Idea how to set up a node loop and reading about it is just confusing me more.

Can someone help and possibly explain this to me so I can make sense of it for future reference.

Thanks

This is the code I currently have, I just don't know how to make it target all elements with that class rather than just the first element with that class.

```
var btnSwirls = document.createElement('div');
    btnSwirls.id = 'dbtb-button-swirl-wrap';
    btnSwirls.className = 'dbtb-button-swirl-wrap';
    document.getElementsByClassName("dbtb-add-btn-assets")[0].appendChild(btnSwirls);
```

Comment: Use a loop instead of accessing `[0]` only?

Comment: or you can use querySelectorAll - like `document.querySelectorAll("dbtb-add-btn-assets").forEach(el => el.appendChild(btnSwirls))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are  handling an "array" of elements. For that, you'd need a loop to iterate over the array.

you shouldn't be using this
document.getElementsByClassName("dbtb-add-btn-assets")[0] <-- because this part [0] denotes that you are targeting the first element in the array, hence 0, since all arrays start with the index 0; i.e. [0, 1, 2, 3, ...] indices

so for iterating over an array you can either use a (for loop) or a (for of) loop

for loop:

```
let dbtb_add_btn_assets = document.getElementsByClassName("dbtb-add-btn-assets"); //you are assigning a variable to the array;

for(let i = 0; i < dbtb_add_btn_assets.length; i++) {
  var btnSwirls = document.createElement('div');
  btnSwirls.id = 'dbtb-button-swirl-wrap';
  btnSwirls.className = 'dbtb-button-swirl-wrap'; //create btnswirls per iteration of the loop
 
  dbtb_add_btn_assets[i].appendChild(btnSwirls); 
}
```

the i is the current index of the loop, the i++ part of the for loop
will automatically add 1 to itself upon executing the statement inside
the for loop and ends when i is not less than the dbtb_add_btn_assets
length. Length meaning the number of elements inside the array.

for of:

```
let dbtb_add_btn_assets = document.querySelectorAll('.dbtb-add-btn-assets'); //personally I'd use querySelectorAll instead of getElementsByCLassName just add . for classes # for ids

for(let dbtb of dbtb_add_btn_assets) { //name whatever variable you want to use
 var btnSwirls = document.createElement('div');
  btnSwirls.id = 'dbtb-button-swirl-wrap';
  btnSwirls.className = 'dbtb-button-swirl-wrap'; //create btnswirls per dbtb

  dbtb.appendChild(btnSwirls);
}
```

the for of loop takes the contents from a specified array and put them into a temporary variable, successfully giving access to the individual content/object, and then automatically iterates over each one as you manipulate it however you like inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you, that worked first try! I kept seeing that first option but I couldn't make sense of it but how you've explained it helped a lot. I don't quite follow how the second one sets up a loop? could you explain how that one works to me?

Comment: @Jason_C The for of loop takes each content of an array and puts it into a new temporary variable accessible only to the for of loop. In this  case the dbtb variable. 
You can name it whatever you like.

the for part of it starts the for loop, the let dbtb is the new variable you're going to assign the individual array contents, and the of <array name> is self explanatory.

It's basically saying, take each content from the array dbtb_add_btn_assets and put them into dbtb variable. Then you can do whatever inside, since you have the reference of the dbtb variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
const btnSwirls = document.createElement('div');
btnSwirls.id = 'dbtb-button-swirl-wrap';
btnSwirls.className = 'dbtb-button-swirl-wrap';

document.getElementsByClassName("dbtb-add-btn-assets").forEach(element => {
  element.appendChild(btnSwirls);
})
```

learn more about `forEach()`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXb5LN_opbA

learn more about arrow functions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h33Srr5J9nY

learn more about `var`, `let`, and `const`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WIJQDvt4Us

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over all the elements. You only access the first of many elements using `[0]`.

There are multiple ways to do this.
Here are two ways to do it using a sample application which just toggles a class (adds/ removes a class) every two seconds.

#### #1 - Use `querySelectorAll()` and `forEach()`

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of HTML elements which match the given [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) `.someClass`.

> Notice that the CSS selector requires a `.` before a class name.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
  const allElements = document.querySelectorAll(".someClass");
  // add/ remove class every 2 seconds 
  setInterval(() => {
    // loop over all elements and add/ remove a class
    allElements.forEach(element => {
      element.classList.toggle("anotherClass");
    });
  }, 2000)
})
```

```css
.someClass {
  padding: 20;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
}

.anotherClass {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="someClass">div 1</div>
<div class="someClass">div 2</div>
<div class="someClass">div 3</div>
<div class="someClass">div 4</div>
```

#### #2 - Use `getElementsByClassName()` and `for .. of ...` loop

Alternatively you can use [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) which returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). You can then use a [`for ... of ...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to iterate over all the elements in the collection.

> Notice that here for the `getElementsByClassName()` call we **MUST NOT** use a `.` before the class name.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
  const allElements = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass");
  // loop 
  setInterval(() => {
    // loop over all elements and add/ remove a class
    for (const element of allElements) {
      element.classList.toggle("anotherClass");
    }
  }, 2000)
})
```

```css
.someClass {
  padding: 20;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
}

.anotherClass {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="someClass">div 1</div>
<div class="someClass">div 2</div>
<div class="someClass">div 3</div>
<div class="someClass">div 4</div>
```

> Please note: You should use [`DOMContentLoaded event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) so you wait till the HTML document is ready before you try to access the DOM.